# How to pass options to command using cygwin run.exe

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin

I want to execute a bash command with my user environment, and I do not want  to open a terminal windows on my Windows desktop. I tried:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe zsh -lic emacs
```

And it opens a emacs window with my user environment. But if I try:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe zsh -lic emacs --name fancy-name
```

It seems the `--name` option is ineffective.

I tried to add quote, but did not work.

What I want to achieve is to use `--eval` option in Emacs to initialize my Emacs according to my command context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get Emacs to interpret its flags on my setup if I wrap things in two sets of quotes, like this:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe bash -lic '"emacs -q"'
```

(All of this is in a `cmd` window, by the way.  And I'm assuming that `zsh` and `bash` are not different in any way relevant to the question.)

I think what's happening here is that `run` is stripping one level of quotes before it hands things off to `bash`.  However, I don't think you need the extra level of indirection.  This also works for me:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -lic "emacs -q"
```

---

EDIT: But of course you're using the `--eval` switch with Emacs, which means you'll want to use quotes with whatever you want evaluated.  The hitch here is that the argument to eval also needs to be quoted, e.g.

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe bash -lic '"emacs --eval \"(foo)\""'
```

To quote strings inside that, you'll need to replace the outer single quotes with doubles and double- and triple-escape as necessary:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe bash -lic "\"emacs --eval \\\"(message \\\\\\\"Foo\\\\\\\")\\\"\""
```

Of course that gets nuts pretty quickly.  String literal syntax makes things a little saner by using single quotes while still allowing you to escape single quotes inside the string:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe bash -lic "\"emacs --eval $'(message \\\"Foo\\\")'\""
```

Finally, there's the option of just encapsulating the code you want to evaluate as a function inside Emacs so you can call it without string or symbol literals.  Alternatively, you could put it in a file and have Emacs load it with the `-l` switch.

Comment: Thanks for the single quote trick. But still, I cannot get this one work: `d:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe zsh -lic '"emacs --eval (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create \"sss\"))"'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: The immediate problem is that you need to put the entire argument to eval inside quotes, but after that I can't figure out a way to quote strings inside that.  See my edit for another idea.

Comment: And I figured out how to get string literals to work.  I'm still not sure I'd recommend using them over encapsulating the code as a function or file, but you can if you need to.